# Visual Studio Angular Compiler Errors

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

I get the following errors in the Error List panel of Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.4).  They started showing up after I updated Visual Studio to this version.  I vaguely remember something about the Typescript version changing, but I don't remember what it said exactly.

The errors prevent the application from launching, but if I close and re-open Visual Studio the app will run fine.

The angular application is using Angular 2.

How do I prevent these errors from appearing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the .csproj file, as the last item of the node

```
<PropertyGroup>
```

insert the following:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

you can disable the typescript compilation on VS2017 in that way. However, this is more a workaround than a **[`solution.`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24584/cant-compile-the-ts-files-on-vs2017-node-modules-n.html)**

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else: I think the real problem is that after updating Visual Studio, the built-in TypeScript SDK was also updated.  For whatever reason the VS TypeScript SDK in VS 15.7.4 does not include TypeScript 2.3 that my angular project.json is using, VS only has 3.0, 2.8, 2.1 available in project properties > TypeScript Build.

So...it's one of those "watch out" things that seems to happen with Angular projects and Visual Studio now.  In the .NET glory days, we used to be able to update Visual Studio and not have to worry about it breaking our projects -- not so much any more.